# How to read objects from an input file and write to an output file

Tags: java, recursion, file-io

I am a computer science student and am currently learning about recursion. I am doing my project on recursion and writing to an output text file, due later this week. It is a class of Students (CS152) and it must print all the students, the best student, and the amount of honors students in the class.

Student Class:

```
public class Student
{
    String lastName, firstName, id;
    double gpa;
    int year;

    public Student(String lastName, String firstName, String id, double gpa, int year)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.id = id;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "NAME: " + lastName + ", " + firstName + "\n";

        result += "ID: " + id + "\n";
        result += "GPA: " + gpa + "\n";
        result += "YEAR: " + year + "\n";

        return result;
    }

    public boolean isHonors()
    {
        if (this.gpa > 3.5)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean isBetter(Student s)
    {   
        if(this.gpa > s.getGPA())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public double getGPA()
    {
        return gpa;
    }

}
```

CS152 Class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CS152
{
    public static final int MAXSIZE = 22;
    private static int size = 0;

    public CS152() throws IOException
    {
        Scanner fileScan;
        String firstName, lastName, id;
        double gpa;
        int year;

        fileScan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

        createList(fileScan);
     }             

     public static Student[] createList(Scanner scan)
     {
         Student[] list = new Student[MAXSIZE];
         return populateList(list, scan);
     }

     private static Student[] populateList(Student[] list, Scanner scan)
     {
         Student s;
         if (size < MAXSIZE && scan.hasNext())
         {
             s = new Student(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextInt());
             list[size] = s;
             size++;
             return populateList(list, scan);
         }
         else
             return list;
     }

     public static int getSize()
     {
         return size;
     }

     public static String toString(Student[] list, int n)
     {
         String str = "";
         if(n == 1)
         {
             str += list[0].toString();
         }
         else
         {
             str += list[n-1].toString();
             toString(list,n-1);
         }
     return str;
     }

     public static Student findBestStudent(Student[] list, int n)
     {
         if(n==1)
             return list[0];
         else
         {
             Student temp = findBestStudent(list, n-1);
             if(temp.isBetter(list[n-1]))
                 return temp;
             else
                 return list[n-1];
         }
     }

     public static int countHonors(Student[] list, int n)
     {
         if(n==0)
             return 0;
         else
         {
             if(list[n-1].isHonors())
                 return countHonors(list, n-1) + 1;
             else
                 return countHonors(list, n-1);
         }
     }
 }
```

TestRecursion Class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class TestRecursion
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        CS152 cs152 = new CS152();
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        cs152.createList(fileScan);

        String file = "output.txt";

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(bw);

        for(int line=1; line <= cs152.getSize(); line++)
        {
            for(int num=1; num <= cs152.getSize(); num++)
            {
                outFile.print(cs152);
            }
        }

        outFile.close();
        System.out.println("Output file has been created: " + file);
    }
}
```

Input File:

```
Zombie Rob 0001 3.5 2013
Smith John 0002 3.2 2012
Jane Mary 0003 3.8 2014
Thekid Billy 0004 2.9 1850
Earp Wyatt 0005 1.5 1862
Holiday Doc 0006 1.4 1863
Cool Annie 0007 4.0 2013
Presley Elvis 0008 3.1 2011
```

My expected output for each Student is:

```
NAME: Zombie Rob
ID: 0001
GPA: 3.5
YEAR: 2013

Best Student: (Whoever the best student is)
Amount of Honors Students: (amount of students)
```

My output file just comes out like:

```
CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12CS152@5abc3c12
```

I know I have to add more to print out the best student and the amount of honors students, but but right now I just can't seem to figure out if there's a problem with my toString method in my CS152 class, or how I'm getting the information from the file, or how I'm writing to the file, or if its something else. I am completely lost. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Learn how to override the toString() behavior in your objects.  What you observe is the default behavior in java.lang.Object.  Your Student class looks fine; I'm guessing you are seeing references for Student arrays.  You need to loop over the arrays and call toString() on each Student it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is confusing.

Here's how I refactored it.  My version writes this text to output.txt:

```
[Student{lastName='Zombie', firstName='Rob', id='0001', gpa=3.5, year=2013}, Student{lastName='Smith', firstName='John', id='0002', gpa=3.2, year=2012}, Student{lastName='Jane', firstName='Mary', id='0003', gpa=3.8, year=2014}, Student{lastName='Thekid', firstName='Billy', id='0004', gpa=2.9, year=1850}, Student{lastName='Earp', firstName='Wyatt', id='0005', gpa=1.5, year=1862}, Student{lastName='Holiday', firstName='Doc', id='0006', gpa=1.4, year=1863}, Student{lastName='Cool', firstName='Annie', id='0007', gpa=4.0, year=2013}, Student{lastName='Presley', firstName='Elvis', id='0008', gpa=3.1, year=2011}]
Best Student: Optional[Student{lastName='Cool', firstName='Annie', id='0007', gpa=4.0, year=2013}]
# of honors students: 2
```

Your recursive methods are not correct.  They don't read the input file, determine best student, or count honors students correctly at all.

I refactored the code using Java 8.  It's probably too much if you're a beginner, but it works and provides an example of how to do it differently.

Student:

```
/**
 * Student class
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 4/5/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439416/how-to-read-objects-from-an-input-file-and-write-to-an-output-file
 */
public class Student {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String id;
    private double gpa;
    private int year;

    public Student(String lastName, String firstName, String id, double gpa, int year) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.id = id;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public boolean isHonors() {
        return this.gpa > 3.5;
    }

    public double getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Student{");
        sb.append("lastName='").append(lastName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", firstName='").append(firstName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", id='").append(id).append('\'');
        sb.append(", gpa=").append(gpa);
        sb.append(", year=").append(year);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

StudentFactory:

```
/**
 * StudentFactory
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 4/5/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439416/how-to-read-objects-from-an-input-file-and-write-to-an-output-file
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentFactory {

    public List<Student> getStudentList(Scanner scanner) {
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (StudentFactory.isNotBlank(line)) {
                String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
                studentList.add(new Student(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]), Integer.parseInt(tokens[4])));
            }
        }
        return studentList;
    }

    public Optional<Student> getBestStudent(List<Student> studentList) {
        return studentList.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Student::getGpa));
    }

    public long countHonors(List<Student> studentList) {
        return studentList.stream().filter(Student::isHonors).count();
    }

    public static boolean isNotBlank(String s) {
        return (s != null) && !"".equals(s.trim());
    }
}
```

It's never too early to learn about [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/):

```
/**
 * JUnit test for StudentFactory
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 4/5/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439416/how-to-read-objects-from-an-input-file-and-write-to-an-output-file
 */

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentFactoryTest {

    private StudentFactory studentFactory = new StudentFactory();
    private List<Student> studentList;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("./src/test/resources/input.txt"));
        this.studentFactory = new StudentFactory();
        this.studentList = studentFactory.getStudentList(fileScan);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStudentList() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Assert.assertEquals(8, studentList.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetBestStudent() {
        String expected = "Optional[Student{lastName='Cool', firstName='Annie', id='0007', gpa=4.0, year=2013}]";
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, this.studentFactory.getBestStudent(this.studentList).toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCountHonors() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2L, this.studentFactory.countHonors(this.studentList));
    }

    public void printOutput(String outputFileName) {
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName))) {
            pw.println(this.studentList);
            pw.println("best student: " + studentFactory.getBestStudent(studentList));
            pw.println("# of honors students: " + studentFactory.countHonors(studentList));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the memory address to the file, that's what the @5abc3c12 is.  use:

```
toString()
```

method when writing non-primitives to file if you want text. If you want the formatting in your output, make use of the

```
\n
```

and ensure you aren't crashing on spaces and such.  Remember about adding delimiters to be able to fetch data from file. If you want to store full objects, look into serialisation